# Selecionar o nome da Controller através de JavaScript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho o código abaixo e gostaria de adicionar a `class="current"` a `<li></li>` de acordo com a controller que estou acessando.

Quero fazer isto para que o item fique em destaque.

```
  <ul class="nav">
   <!-- Main menu -->
   <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
   <li><a href="calendar.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> Calendar</a></li>
   <li><a href="stats.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i> Statistics (Charts)</a></li>
   <li><a href="tables.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Tables</a></li>
   <li><a href="forms.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i> Forms</a></li>
   <li class="submenu">
      <a href="#">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Pages
      <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
      </a>
      <!-- Sub menu -->
      <ul>
         <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Como faço para pegar o nome da *controller/action* na view?

Pensei em pegar o nome da controller/action e através de jQuery alterar a classe do `<li></li>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  *window.location.pathname* para obter a *Url* corrente.

Use `Split("/")` para dividir a URL.

A primeira posição indica o `dominio`, seguido pelo `Controller` e por ultimo a `Action`.

Veja o resultado de:
`console.log(window.location.pathname.split("/"));`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Como alternativa, você pode definir um ID para cada `<li>` e inserir a classe current a cada chamada da controller. Dessa forma, não precisará se preocupar com qual controller está sendo acessada e o código fica mais simples de compreender e dar manutenção.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente uso o seguinte:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```

[Veja mais sobre `ViewContext` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext(v=vs.118).aspx).

Adicionalmente, você pode implementar essas duas *Extensions* que tornam o procedimento mais simples:

```
public class HtmlExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ativa a class no menu à esquerda.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper"></param>
    /// <param name="Actionvalue"></param>
    /// <param name="Controllervalue">array de controllers.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IHtmlString Ativar(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] Controllervalue)
    {
        var currentController =
            (helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().UnDash();

        var estaNaController = Controllervalue.Contains(currentController);

        var resultado = estaNaController ? new HtmlString("active") : new HtmlString(string.Empty);
        return resultado;
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///    Remover traços ("-") a partir do valor determinado objeto representado como uma cadeia e retorna uma cadeia vazia ( "")
    ///     quando o tipo de instância não poderia ser representado como uma string.
    ///     <para>
    ///         Nota: Isto irá retornar o nome  tipo de determinada instância. Seo runtime type não seja uma string!
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The object instance to undash when represented as its string value.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string UnDash(this object value)
    {
        return ((value as string) ?? string.Empty).UnDash();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Removes dashes ("-") from the given string value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The string value that optionally contains dashes.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string UnDash(this string value)
    {
        return (value ?? string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
<li class="@Html.Ativar("Topico1", "Topico2", "Topico3")">
```

Serve para ativar menus *collapsible*, em que a classe ativa é a do menu pai.